# Find all pixel coordinates in a specified region using PIL, kernel crashes

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, stack-overflow

I have some code find to all the pixels within a region of an image. This region is bounded by two straight lines sharing the same origin and extended until the edge of the image (a wedge shape). I supply the function with a starting point inside this region as a parameter and use recursion to get all the pixels inside it. The problem is that it only works for very small "wedges".

```
import threading
threading.stack_size(99999999)

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(2**30)

pix=im.load()
pixels=[]
memo=[]
count=0

def flood_wedge(x,y):
    global count
    count+=1
    #memo records every pixel visited 
    memo.append([x,y])
    if ([x,y] in pixels) or ([x,y] in pixels_1) or ([x,y] in pixels_2):
        pass
    else:
        try:
            #if (x,y) is outside the image, pix[x,y] returns an error 
            pix[x,y]=(256,51,51)
            #pixels is the desired list
            pixels.append([x,y])
        except:
            pass
        else:
            if ([x+1,y] not in memo):
                flood_wedge(x+1,y)
            if ([x-1,y] not in memo):
                flood_wedge(x-1,y)
            if ([x,y+1] not in memo):
                flood_wedge(x,y+1)
            if ([x,y-1] not in memo):
                flood_wedge(x,y-1)
```

I have tried increasing the recursion limit, though depth isn't necessarily the problem. If increased, the kernel just crashes. I tried increasing the stack size, but it made no difference at all. The code actually runs pretty fast, but increasing the size of the region just slightly causes this problem. Ultimately, I would need to use this on large images (.tif).

[sample small wedge on a 946x710 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVoHM.png)

Comment: Recursion is just pretty bad. You could just go through the height and add each pixel in each horizontal line to 'memo'.

Comment: You could try making `memo` a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of `(x, y)` tuples instead of a `list` which will automatically eliminate all the duplicates that are getting put into it. This will not only greatly reduce the amount of memory needed, it will also likely speed up all the membership-testing that's being done.

Comment: Thanks, martineau. I didn`t know about the set object before. I am updating memo with the .add() method now. It is a good tip, but the code still runs into the same problem.

Comment: Huh? So if you tell me pixel [63,84] is in your wedge, how can I tell if the pixel beside it is in your wedge? Do you tell me the origin of the lines? Or the formula of the lines?

Comment: I have a list with all the coordinate pixels in those lines.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually want to run a *"Connected Component Analysis"*, or a *"labelling"* which assigns a unique number (label) to each *"blob"* of connected (touching) pixels.

You can do that with **OpenCV**'s `findContours()` which is documented [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html), or you can use **scipy**'s `label()` which seems like fun to try out.

I wanted to be sure my method works with more than one "blob" so I added two more lines of the same colour as your wedge:

[image]

The code is pretty self-explanatory, but I wanted to draw your attention to a couple of things.

The mask image I make is black everywhere except where the image is the same colour as the seed pixel and it is white in those places:

[image]

The default SE (Structuring Element) to describe which pixels are considered connected to the central pixel is:

```
SE = 0 1 0
     1 1 1
     0 1 0
```

which is called 4-connected, because the central pixel is connected to the 4 pixels North, East, South and West of it. As your wedge is not rectangular, we need to also consider pixels diagonally touching as neighbours. That means 8-connected and looks like this:

```
SE = 1 1 1
     1 1 1
     1 1 1
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from scipy import ndimage
from scipy.ndimage import label, generate_binary_structure
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load image and ensure RGB - just in case palettised
im = Image.open("sky.png").convert("RGB")

# Make numpy array from image
npimage = np.array(im, dtype=np.uint8)

# Assume we were told to take pixel [17,483] as our seed
seed = npimage[17,483]

# If we had been given a seed colour instead, e.g. red, we would do
# seed = np.array((255,0,0), dtype=np.uint8)

# Make greyscale mask image, generally black but white where same colour as seed
mask = (np.all((npimage==seed),axis=-1)*255).astype(np.uint8) 

# The default SE (structuring element) is for 4-connectedness, i.e. only pixels North, South, East and West of another are considered connected.
# Pixels in our wedge are 8-connected, i.e. N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W, NW, so we need a corresponding SE
SE = generate_binary_structure(2,2)   

# Now run a labelling, or "Connected Components Analysis"
# Each "blob" of connected pixels matching our seed will get assigned a unique number in the new image called "labeled"
labeled, nr_objects = ndimage.label(mask, structure=SE)

print('Num objects found: {}'.format(nr_objects))

# Get label assigned to our blob, and its area
ourlabel = labeled[17,483]
area     = np.bincount(labeled.flat)[ourlabel:ourlabel+1]
print('Our blob got label: {} and has area: {}'.format(ourlabel,area))

# Now print list of pixels in our blob
print(*np.argwhere(labeled==ourlabel))
```

---

Here is the output:

```
Num objects found: 3
Our blob got label: 1 and has area: [530]
[  0 475] [  0 476] [  0 477] [  0 478] [  0 479] [  0 480] [  0 481] [  0 482] [  0 483] [  0 484] [  0 485] [  0 486] [  0 487] [  0 488] [  0 489] [  0 490] [  0 491] [  0 492] [  0 493] [  0 494] [  0 495] [  0 496] [  0 497] [  0 498] [  0 499] [  0 500] [  0 501] [  0 502] [  0 503] [  0 504] [  0 505] [  1 475] [  1 476] [  1 477] [  1 478] [  1 479] [  1 480] [  1 481] [  1 482] [  1 483] [  1 484] [  1 485] [  1 486] [  1 487] [  1 488] [  1 489] [  1 490] [  1 491] [  1 492] [  1 493] [  1 494] [  1 495] [  1 496] [  1 497] [  1 498] [  1 499] [  1 500] [  1 501] [  1 502] [  1 503] [  1 504] [  2 475] [  2 476] [  2 477] [  2 478] [  2 479] [  2 480] [  2 481] [  2 482] [  2 483] [  2 484] [  2 485] [  2 486] [  2 487] [  2 488] [  2 489] [  2 490] [  2 491] [  2 492] [  2 493] [  2 494] [  2 495] [  2 496] [  2 497] [  2 498] [  2 499] [  2 500] [  2 501] [  2 502] [  2 503] [  3 475] [  3 476] [  3 477] [  3 478] [  3 479] [  3 480] [  3 481] [  3 482] [  3 483] [  3 484] [  3 485] [  3 486] [  3 487] [  3 488] [  3 489] [  3 490] [  3 491] [  3 492] [  3 493] [  3 494] [  3 495] [  3 496] [  3 497] [  3 498] [  3 499] [  3 500] [  3 501] [  3 502] [  4 475] [  4 476] [  4 477] [  4 478] [  4 479] [  4 480] [  4 481] [  4 482] [  4 483] [  4 484] [  4 485] [  4 486] [  4 487] [  4 488] [  4 489] [  4 490] [  4 491] [  4 492] [  4 493] [  4 494] [  4 495] [  4 496] [  4 497] [  4 498] [  4 499] [  4 500] [  4 501] [  5 475] [  5 476] [  5 477] [  5 478] [  5 479] [  5 480] [  5 481] [  5 482] [  5 483] [  5 484] [  5 485] [  5 486] [  5 487] [  5 488] [  5 489] [  5 490] [  5 491] [  5 492] [  5 493] [  5 494] [  5 495] [  5 496] [  5 497] [  5 498] [  5 499] [  5 500] [  6 475] [  6 476] [  6 477] [  6 478] [  6 479] [  6 480] [  6 481] [  6 482] [  6 483] [  6 484] [  6 485] [  6 486] [  6 487] [  6 488] [  6 489] [  6 490] [  6 491] [  6 492] [  6 493] [  6 494] [  6 495] [  6 496] [  6 497] [  6 498] [  6 499] [  7 475] [  7 476] [  7 477] [  7 478] [  7 479] [  7 480] [  7 481] [  7 482] [  7 483] [  7 484] [  7 485] [  7 486] [  7 487] [  7 488] [  7 489] [  7 490] [  7 491] [  7 492] [  7 493] [  7 494] [  7 495] [  7 496] [  7 497] [  7 498] [  8 475] [  8 476] [  8 477] [  8 478] [  8 479] [  8 480] [  8 481] [  8 482] [  8 483] [  8 484] [  8 485] [  8 486] [  8 487] [  8 488] [  8 489] [  8 490] [  8 491] [  8 492] [  8 493] [  8 494] [  8 495] [  8 496] [  8 497] [  9 475] [  9 476] [  9 477] [  9 478] [  9 479] [  9 480] [  9 481] [  9 482] [  9 483] [  9 484] [  9 485] [  9 486] [  9 487] [  9 488] [  9 489] [  9 490] [  9 491] [  9 492] [  9 493] [  9 494] [  9 495] [  9 496] [ 10 475] [ 10 476] [ 10 477] [ 10 478] [ 10 479] [ 10 480] [ 10 481] [ 10 482] [ 10 483] [ 10 484] [ 10 485] [ 10 486] [ 10 487] [ 10 488] [ 10 489] [ 10 490] [ 10 491] [ 10 492] [ 10 493] [ 10 494] [ 10 495] [ 11 475] [ 11 476] [ 11 477] [ 11 478] [ 11 479] [ 11 480] [ 11 481] [ 11 482] [ 11 483] [ 11 484] [ 11 485] [ 11 486] [ 11 487] [ 11 488] [ 11 489] [ 11 490] [ 11 491] [ 11 492] [ 11 493] [ 11 494] [ 12 475] [ 12 476] [ 12 477] [ 12 478] [ 12 479] [ 12 480] [ 12 481] [ 12 482] [ 12 483] [ 12 484] [ 12 485] [ 12 486] [ 12 487] [ 12 488] [ 12 489] [ 12 490] [ 12 491] [ 12 492] [ 12 493] [ 13 475] [ 13 476] [ 13 477] [ 13 478] [ 13 479] [ 13 480] [ 13 481] [ 13 482] [ 13 483] [ 13 484] [ 13 485] [ 13 486] [ 13 487] [ 13 488] [ 13 489] [ 13 490] [ 13 491] [ 13 492] [ 14 475] [ 14 476] [ 14 477] [ 14 478] [ 14 479] [ 14 480] [ 14 481] [ 14 482] [ 14 483] [ 14 484] [ 14 485] [ 14 486] [ 14 487] [ 14 488] [ 14 489] [ 14 490] [ 14 491] [ 15 475] [ 15 476] [ 15 477] [ 15 478] [ 15 479] [ 15 480] [ 15 481] [ 15 482] [ 15 483] [ 15 484] [ 15 485] [ 15 486] [ 15 487] [ 15 488] [ 15 489] [ 15 490] [ 16 475] [ 16 476] [ 16 477] [ 16 478] [ 16 479] [ 16 480] [ 16 481] [ 16 482] [ 16 483] [ 16 484] [ 16 485] [ 16 486] [ 16 487] [ 16 488] [ 16 489] [ 17 474] [ 17 475] [ 17 476] [ 17 477] [ 17 478] [ 17 479] [ 17 480] [ 17 481] [ 17 482] [ 17 483] [ 17 484] [ 17 485] [ 17 486] [ 17 487] [ 17 488] [ 18 474] [ 18 475] [ 18 476] [ 18 477] [ 18 478] [ 18 479] [ 18 480] [ 18 481] [ 18 482] [ 18 483] [ 18 484] [ 18 485] [ 18 486] [ 18 487] [ 18 488] [ 19 474] [ 19 475] [ 19 476] [ 19 477] [ 19 478] [ 19 479] [ 19 480] [ 19 481] [ 19 482] [ 19 483] [ 19 484] [ 19 485] [ 19 486] [ 19 487] [ 20 474] [ 20 475] [ 20 476] [ 20 477] [ 20 478] [ 20 479] [ 20 480] [ 20 481] [ 20 482] [ 20 483] [ 20 484] [ 20 485] [ 20 486] [ 21 474] [ 21 475] [ 21 476] [ 21 477] [ 21 478] [ 21 479] [ 21 480] [ 21 481] [ 21 482] [ 21 483] [ 21 484] [ 21 485] [ 22 474] [ 22 475] [ 22 476] [ 22 477] [ 22 478] [ 22 479] [ 22 480] [ 22 481] [ 22 482] [ 22 483] [ 22 484] [ 23 474] [ 23 475] [ 23 476] [ 23 477] [ 23 478] [ 23 479] [ 23 480] [ 23 481] [ 23 482] [ 23 483] [ 24 474] [ 24 475] [ 24 476] [ 24 477] [ 24 478] [ 24 479] [ 24 480] [ 24 481] [ 24 482] [ 25 474] [ 25 475] [ 25 476] [ 25 477] [ 25 478] [ 25 479] [ 25 480] [ 25 481] [ 26 474] [ 26 475] [ 26 476] [ 26 477] [ 26 478] [ 26 479] [ 26 480] [ 27 474] [ 27 475] [ 27 476] [ 27 477] [ 27 478] [ 27 479] [ 28 474] [ 28 475] [ 28 476] [ 28 477] [ 28 478] [ 29 474] [ 29 475] [ 29 476] [ 29 477] [ 30 473] [ 30 474] [ 30 475] [ 30 476] [ 31 473] [ 31 474] [ 31 475] [ 32 473] [ 32 474] [ 33 473]
```

---

You can do this possibly more simply just at the command line with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

Firstly, make everything that is not the same colour red as your wedge into black pixels:

```
convert sky.png -alpha off -fill black +opaque "srgb(255,51,51)" mask.png
```

[image]

Now that you have seen how that works, do the same thing again but this time continue and run a *"Connected Component Analysis"* as well:

```
convert sky.png -alpha off -fill black +opaque "srgb(255,51,51)"  \
    -define connected-components:verbose=true                     \
    -connected-components 8 -normalize  output.png
```

**Sample Output**

```
Objects (id: bounding-box centroid area mean-color):
  0: 946x707+0+0 472.5,353.1 665950 srgb(0,0,0)
  3: 173x341+299+300 385.0,470.0 1531 srgb(255,51,51)
  2: 33x201+599+200 615.0,300.0 811 srgb(255,51,51)
  1: 33x34+473+0 484.5,11.0 530 srgb(255,51,51)        <--- this is your wedge
```

That means 3 red areas were found, namely the last three lines where `srgb(255,51,51)` and the last one is an area 33x34 pixels located 473,0 pixels across from the top-left corner and it has an area of 530 pixels just the same as we found with Python.

Comment: Thank you, Mark Setchell. This is really interesting stuff, but unfortunately not useful for my problem. Ultimately, I want to analyse some images, so I will not change the color of any region. The only reason I colored the wedge red was to confirm that the code was correctly identifying the coordinates of all pixels inside that region. In fact, the only reason I was able to color the region was because I had already identified all those coordinates. I wrote new code using a few loops, but it is probably not the best solution. So I am still open to any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

With only that one image, it's hard to tell if this will be fully generalizable for your purposes, but it does work in this case.  IT will need some tweaking if the wedge isn't always on the top edge or if the image content isn't so easily filtered out.  You seem to have a pretty good handle on locating the wedge amongst the image noise though so that part probably doesn't matter to you.  I'll include it just in case, but the important part for you is probably at the bottom of the code block.  The rest is just how I isolated the wedge  You should be able to label the objects in the image, and then use the lines as the bounding point for the pixels.

```
import imageio
import skimage
import numpy
import scipy.ndimage.filters
import skimage.io
import skimage.filters
import skimage.morphology


image = imageio.imread(r'C:\Users\Jeremiah\Pictures\wedge.png')
image_array = numpy.float64(image)

R_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 0], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
G_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 1], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
B_x = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 2], [[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])

R_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 0], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
G_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 1], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
B_y = scipy.ndimage.filters.correlate(image_array[:, :, 2], [[1, 0 , -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])

Jacobian_x = R_x**2 + G_x**2 + B_x**2
Jacobian_y = R_y**2 + G_y**2 + B_y**2
Jacobian_xy = R_x * R_y + G_x * G_y + B_x * B_y
Determinant = numpy.sqrt(numpy.fabs((Jacobian_x**2) - (2 * Jacobian_x * Jacobian_y) + (Jacobian_y**2) + 4 * (Jacobian_xy**2)))
Maximum_Eigenvalue = (Jacobian_x + Jacobian_y + Determinant) / 2
Edges = numpy.sqrt(Maximum_Eigenvalue)

Threshold = skimage.filters.threshold_mean(Edges)
Binary_Image = Edges > Threshold    
labeled_Edges, features = scipy.ndimage.label(Edges)

sliced = scipy.ndimage.find_objects(labeled_Edges)[0]
slices = image[sliced]

>>>(slice(0, 36, None), slice(471, 508, None))
>>>[[[  0   0   0 255]
   [  0   0   0 255]
   [  0   0   0 255]
   ...
   [255  51  51 255]
   [255 255 255 255]
   [  0   0   0 255]]
```

The pixels you want are contained within those slices, no recursion needed...I think.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremiah. I don`t understand your code, but I think you are finding the wedge based on the red coloring, right? If this is the case, it will not work, as I colored that wedge to illustrate a region where my code worked (in finding the coordinates of all those points). So, I`m trying to find the pixel coordinates inside the known wedge boundaries (pixels_1, pixels_2 and the image edges).

Comment: Oh sorry. I should have commented it better. No, the red coloring doesn’t matter. I’m using a sober filter to find the edges of the objects in the image, thresholding to convert the edge image to black & white, and then labeling each object in the image that isn’t connected to any other objects. It will work As is If the wedge is at the top of the image and doesn’t cross the noise in the image below it..

Comment: If the wedge isn’t on top, it won’t be the first object in the object array, so the wedge won’t be at index [0]. If it crosses the noise, the way the noise is cleared will have to be tweaked so it doesn’t clear out the wedge